# Formulario adicionado a página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função javascript que carrega formularios a partir de arquivos XML. Os arquivos contem apenas os códigos dos formulários, inputs, selects, etc... Esses dados são carregados dinamicamente para uma página através da função load() do jquery. Logo em seguida uma outra função popula esses campos recuperando dados de um array json carregado anteriormente. Porém esses dados não aparecem nos campos, como se o formulário não estivesse carregado/sincronizado na página. Alguém já passou por isso? Tem uma luz?

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o código e xml ou json que estás a usar?

Comment: Desculpe, os formulários estão em HTML e não em XML como mencionado. Utilizo o a seguinte instrução para adicionar o formulário: '$('#div').load(formulario.html);' . Para popular, itero um array de objetos comparando o nome da chave com o nome do controle. Se forem iguais, adiciono o valor do array para o controle.

Answer (score 0):

O Método `load()` do JQuery é assíncrono.

O que ocorre é que quando você faz a chamada provavelmente ele ainda não tenha gerado os elementos.

Você pode evitar isso usando o *callback* do método.

Ex:

```
$('#div').load('formulario.html',function(){
     //adicionar aqui o preenchimento dos campos
});
```

Comment: Perfeito!!! Funcionou! Obrigado!!!